# Android VR SDK expose ExoPlayer

Tags: android, google-vr

I'm using the [VR sdk](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/) and when trying to play an online video (working on iOS), it gives this error

> Internal track renderer error.
>   com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException:
>       com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.

that sounds like something I could provide to the `ExoPlayer` if I could have direct access to it.

Is there any way I can configure the player using the `VR` SDK?

Is there an alternative way for a 360 video player in Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can flag the video as HLS this way:

```
VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
options.inputFormat = VrVideoView.Options.FORMAT_HLS;
```

and then just

```
vrVideoView.loadVideo(VIDEO_URI, options);
```